# c#: How to consume webservice methods whose address is unknown at compile-time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

I am consuming a webservice from a Java server. The webservice provides me with some methods that need. Up till now I have been using the method where I added the reference of the webservice in the project explorer, typed the address of the webservice and compiled it. But now I need it to pick up the address of the service at runtime from an xml file or something! is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is `Url` property in generated proxy object that you can set at runtime. Covered in [Creating the Web Service Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx) article on MSDN.

Sample from the article (shows how to also set credentials, you may also need to set `Proxy`):

```
var rs = new ReportExecutionService();
rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx?wsdl";
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Note that above answer is for case when you don't know exact Url of server till runtime, but you have WSDL/sample server available at design time and able to generate proxy via add web service in VS (or manually).

Alternatively you can call service via other classes implementing "HTTP GET" like `HttpClient` and configure anything you want, but will need to do your own parsing of results.

Comment: I am not willing to do the parsing myself. It is going to blow the difficulty out of proportion. The project is not worth it. I would just like to be able to specify the URL of the wsdl at runtime. Is that not possible easily?

Comment: @Marci-man - I guess I completely misunderstood your question - you may want to clarify your question. Are you trying to call service that you know nothing about at compile time and somehow be able to use resulting proxy while writing code? (My answer is for case when you don't know exact Url of server till runtime, but you have WSDL/sampe server available at design time)

Comment: Well, I guess you have understood right. I have a wsdl at compile time, but I dont have the server that provides the SOAP service at compile time. I want to be able to provide the address of the server at compile time.

Comment: @Marci-man I'm not sure what else you are looking for - what wrong with setting `Url` at runtime?

Comment: but the link you have provided, suggests that I should use WSDL.exe file to process the wsdl... am I supposed to use the exe at runtime? It also asks to compile the result of wsdl.exe and use the DLL

Comment: @Marci-man Maybe we are reading different article? Mine have 2 parts - one for manually generating proxy, second for using VS: "Adding the Proxy Using a Web Reference in Visual Studio:To add a Web reference to a project.... After you add the Web reference, use the following syntax to create an instance of the proxy class:..."?